# Strange problem with frames (ConTeXt tables)

Tags: tables, context

> **Leads to a bug report on the ConTeXt mailing list: [[dev-context] bTABLE in header and document give unexpected behavior](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-context/2012/002835.html)**

When using this code I get a problem with the frame around the header on the last page. It gets the same frame setting as the table.

This is a screenshot of what I would expect to see:

[image: Good Page]

And this is what I am seeing:

[image: not so good page]

Can someone give me a solution to solve this?

```
% TABLE SETUP
\setupTABLE[frame=on, framecolor=blue, rulethickness=4pt]
\setupTABLE[header][each][background=color, backgroundcolor=blue, color=white]
\setupTABLE[row][odd][background=color, backgroundcolor=gray]
\setupTABLE[row][even][background=color, backgroundcolor=lightgray]
\setupTABLE[row][last][bottomframe=on]
\setupTABLE[row][test][background=color, backgroundcolor=darkgray]
%
% HeaderStyle -------------------------------------------------------------
\startsetups[header]
    \setupTABLE[frame=on]
    \setupTABLE[c][each][width=0.2\textwidth, align=middle, offset=2mm ]
    \setupTABLE[c][4][width=0.6\textwidth]
    \setupTABLE[r][5][height=\headerheight]

    \bTABLE
        \bTR
          \bTD Rev  \eTD \bTD {\ssbfa \getvariable{document}{projectname}} \\ 
                              {\ssbfa \getvariable{document}{documenttitle}}\eTD \bTD some text\eTD        
        \eTR % End of row 1
    \eTABLE 

\stopsetups
\setupheadertexts[\setups{header}]  


\starttext
\startbuffer[table]
\bTABLE[split=repeat]
    \startTABLEhead
        \bTR \bTD No. \eTD \bTD[nc=2] Length         \eTD \eTR
        \bTR \bTD     \eTD \bTD{} [m] \eTD \bTD{} [inch] \eTD \eTR
    \stopTABLEhead
    \startTABLEbody
        \bTR[background=color, backgroundcolor=darkgray] \bTD[nc=3] This is a section where I can place this and that \eTD \eTR
        \dorecurse{100}
        {\bTR \bTD 1.  \eTD \bTD some dummy text.        \eTD \bTD some more dummy text \eTD \eTR}
     \stopTABLEbody
\eTABLE
\stopbuffer

\placetable[split, none]{}{\getbuffer[table]}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Appears to be a bug. Please post a bug report on the ConTeXt mailing list.

Comment: ...which is dev-context@ntg.nl, sign up [here](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/dev-context). (That's for bug reports; for the mailing list with usage discussion, you want ntg-context@ntg.nl [site](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context).)

Comment: The bug report is here: http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-context/2012/002835.html